# Merge identical cells, looping through several columns of an Excel table (listobject)

Tags: loops, merge, listobject

I have a macro generating a new workbook, pasting a selection of data in it, making it an Excel table (listobject), adding data from another table, etc
Now I'm trying to loop through the entire table (working) looking in each column for identical cells to merge them

```
Dim tableName As String
Dim tblcofin As Listobject
Dim v As Long, w As Long
Dim Rg1 As Range, Rg2 As Range
tableName = "CO_FIN"
Set tblcofin = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName)

For v = 1 To Range("CO_FIN").Columns.Count
     For w = 1 To Range("CO_FIN").Rows.Count
            Set Rg1 = tblcofin.DataBodyRange.Cells(w, v)
            Set Rg2 = tblcofin.DataBodyRange.Cells(w + 1, v)

            If Rg1 = Rg2 And Rg1 <> "" Then
                tblcofin.Range(Rg1, Rg2).Merge
            End If
      Next w
 Next v
```

Using Debug.Print lines I was able to confirm that it loops through my whole table, that it identified when 2 cells in the same columns are identical, but I always get an error message "Application-defined or object-defined error" (or another depending on the alternative I tried) for "Range(Rg1, Rg2).Merge"

I tried to:
 - declare Rg1 & Rg2 as Variant rather than Range (setting them with or without adding .Address)
 - use "Cells(Rg1, Rg2).Resize.Merge"
 - and a multitude or other variations
I'm sure it's something very stupid, but though I usually make the point to find the solution by myself, after hours of trying and going through forums, I would really appreciate some advice!
(not sure how to upload a sample file, in case it may help)

I also tried this (adapted from J.A. Gomez) for just my 1st column, to no avail :( (still the same issue on the ".Merge" line...)

```
Dim myFirstRow As Long
Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim myFirstColumn As Long
Dim myLastColumn As Long
Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim iCounter As Long
Dim iCounter2 As Long
    myFirstRow = 6
    myFirstColumn = 2
    myLastColumn = 5
    myLastRow = 21
    Set myWorksheet = Worksheets("Fin_conso")

    With myWorksheet
        For iCounter = myLastRow To myFirstRow Step -1
            iCounter2 = iCounter - 1
            If .Cells(iCounter, myFirstColumn).Value = Cells(iCounter - 1, myFirstColumn).Value Then
Debug.Print .Cells(iCounter, myFirstColumn).Address
                .Range(.Cells(iCounter, myFirstColumn), .Cells(iCounter2, myFirstColumn)).Merge
            End If
        Next iCounter
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours spent looking for a solution, it came to me in a shocking revelation: it's just NOT POSSIBLE to merge cells in a Excel table (listobject), which must have values for filters etc. 
Hope this experience can at least help others wasting time looking like me in the wrong direction!

So I had to unlist the table to make it a normal range, and just had to insert the excellent code from Pk found [here](https://www.pk-anexcelexpert.com/vba-quickly-merge-cells-with-same-value-in-excel/):

```
    Dim RgTable As Range
    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long, FirstCol As Long, LastCol As Long

    Set RgTable = tblcofin.DataBodyRange 'To have a clear range to work from
    'Unlist the tblcofin table to make it just a normal table (not Listobject)
    tblcofin.Unlist

    'Select the range where to merge identical cells
    RgTable.Select

    'Merge identical cells
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim RgM As Range
MergeCells:
        For Each RgM In Selection
            If RgM.Value = RgM.Offset(1, 0).Value And RgM.Value <> "" Then
                Range(RgM, RgM.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
                Range(RgM, RgM.Offset(1, 0)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                Range(RgM, RgM.Offset(1, 0)).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                GoTo MergeCells
            End If
        Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Thanks to the community: I've been learning so much ffrom stackoverflow forum over time. Appreciated!